# How to create tabs on streamlit that work independently

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm trying to create tabs that works independently on Streamlit.

The official documentation explains [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.tabs) how to create three tabs for eg. and it works fine. But when I change the code of (let's say the Cat's tab) so can an error be raised, I can't anymore switch to Dog's tab or Owl's tab.

#### CODE :

```
import streamlit as st

tab1, tab2, tab3 = st.tabs(["Cat", "Dog", "Owl"])

with tab1:
    st.header("A cat")
    st.image("_", width=200) # I changed here on purpose to raise an error

with tab2:
    st.header("A dog")
    st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/dog.jpg", width=200)

with tab3:
    st.header("An owl")
    st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/owl.jpg", width=200)
```

#### ERROR :

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '_'

Do you have any solution to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle that by using `try:` and `except:` then write error message after the `exception` E,g : `st.error("No file found")` or `st.text("No file found")`

```py
import streamlit as st

tab1, tab2, tab3 = st.tabs(["Cat", "Dog", "Owl"])

with tab1:
    st.header("A cat")
    try:
        st.image("_", width=200) # I changed here on purpose to raise an error
    except FileNotFoundError:
        st.text("File not found")

with tab2:
    st.header("A dog")
    try:
        st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/dog.jpg", width=200)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        st.text("File not found")

with tab3:
    st.header("An owl")
    try:
        st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/owl.jpg", width=200)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        st.text("File not found")
```

You can do same with functions that provide individual operations, since you said your first `tab1` holds large data

```py
import streamlit as st

tab1, tab2, tab3 = st.tabs(["Cat", "Dog", "Owl"])

def compute_tab1():
    st.header("A cat")
    try:
        st.image("_", width=200) # I changed here on purpose to raise an error
    except FileNotFoundError:
        st.text("File not found")


def compute_tab2():
    st.header("A dog")
    try:
        st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/dog.jpg", width=200)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        st.text("File not found")

def compute_tab3():
    st.header("An owl")
    try:
        st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/owl.jpg", width=200)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        st.text("File not found")

with tab1:
    compute_tab1()

with tab2:
    compute_tab2()

with tab3:
    compute_tab3()
```

Comment: Imagine if tab1 has a huge amount o instructions to execute, how can we tell Streamlit to bypass tab1 and execute the instructions of the selected tab (tab2 for e.g) ? I tried with `if elif` statements but it doesn't work.

Comment: Huge instructions like what?.. That is not clear. You can provide a demo for that.

Comment: Actually I have three tabs, the first one takes about 1 minute to display the result (because it proccess some big dataframes with pandas), so it means that I can't switch to tab2 unless the tab1's instructions are fully executed. It means I have to wait one minute before switching to tab2 or tab3. I hope I was clear enough this time

Comment: I that case you can you `@cache` to speed up your dataframe process. If you want I can include simple function with `cache` in the answer so you see how it is than in case.

Comment: Even with `@st.cache` this will give a poor user experience since the very first run of the app will be a cache miss, it means that the user will have to wait one minute before he can switch through tabs.

Comment: You can try to create a separate function for `tab1`. That might help, I can edit the the answer to show you how to operate that with functions.

Comment: I am sure with the functions I added below my previous answer will make a difference. You can try using them to see.

Answer (score 0):

## Native solution

You can't do it with tabs. However, you can achieve a similar practical effect with `st.radio()` component.

```
import streamlit as st

animal = st.radio("Your animal:", ["Cat", "Dog", "Owl"])

if animal == "Cat":
    ...
```

External links

- Documentation https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.radio

## 3rd party: Pills

However, from UI perspective, I'd recommend using a third-party library such as steramlit-pills:

`pip install streamlit-pills`

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_pills import pills

animal = pills("Your animal:", ["Cat", "Dog", "Owl"])

if animal == "Cat":
    st.header("A cat")
    st.image("_", width=200) # I changed here on purpose to raise an error

if animal == "Dog":
    st.header("A dog")
    st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/dog.jpg", width=200)

if animal == "Owl":
    st.header("An owl")
    st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/owl.jpg", width=200)
```

External links:

- Demo https://pills-component.streamlit.app/
- Documentation https://github.com/jrieke/streamlit-pills

## 3rd party: Antd

Another alternative would be Antd buttons

`pip install streamlit-antd-components`

```
import streamlit_antd_components as sac

animal = sac.buttons(['Cat', 'Dog', 'Owl'])

if animal == "Cat":
    ...
```

External links

- Demo https://nicedouble-streamlitantdcomponentsdemo-app-middmy.streamlit.app/
- Documentation https://github.com/nicedouble/StreamlitAntdComponents